# SimpleDateFormat doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I try to use this function but it doesn't work with this case '12/05/201a' somebody knows why happen this?

In my test I use this  `System.out.println(isThisDateValid("12/05/201a", "dd/MM/yyyy"));` and the answer was `true` but I'm expected the result would be false because year contains letters.

```
 public static boolean isThisDateValid(String dateToValidate, String dateFromat)
    {

        if (dateToValidate == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFromat);
        sdf.setLenient(false);

        try
        {

            //if not valid, it will throw ParseException
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateToValidate);
            System.out.println(date);

        } catch (ParseException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: its takes `201` for `year`. If you put all letters in place of year it will not parse. Since it expects `1` digit in place of `year`.

Comment: It expects atleast single digit in place of `year`.

Comment: @Reimeus: `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't *ignore* letters, it just doesn't consume the entire string. Here's an example of it not ignoring letters: http://ideone.com/gnbTwy

Comment: @Danielson: The OP is free to format their code how they like.

Comment: @Reimeus: "simply ignores letters" is simply incorrect, however. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`DateFormat#parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) doesn't necessarily use the entire string:

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. **The method may not use the entire text of the given string.**

(*my emphasis*)

[`SimpleDateFormat`'s docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) tell us that `yyyy` doesn't necessarily mean it will require four digits for a year:

> Year:
>
> ...
>
> - For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern `"MM/dd/yyyy"`, `"01/11/12"` parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

So it's correct (if possibly surprising) that it parses that string in the year 201.

You can use [`parse(String,ParsePosition)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) to figure out whether the entire string has been consumed, or validate it with a regular expression before parsing. Here's a version that will check that the whole string has been parsed, and not just the first characters:

```
public static boolean isThisDateValid(String dateToValidate, String dateFormat) {
    if (dateToValidate == null) {
        return false;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    sdf.setLenient(false);

    ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateToValidate, position);
    return date != null && position.getIndex() == dateToValidate.length();
}
```